# Coroutines : Runblocking freeze Android UI

Tags: android, kotlin, asynchronous, freeze, coroutine

I'm developing an android app in Kotlin.
After validation of an entry form, I launch 3 jobs to do 3 http calls in the same time :

```
val jobA = CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
   // saves some data in my database
}
val jobB = CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
   // saves an image in my aws bucket
} 
val jobC = CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
   // if exists, deletes the old image in my aws bucket
}
```

Before launching theses 3 jobs, I start a loader animation
(I'm using this library : https://github.com/81813780/AVLoadingIndicatorView)

I need to wait completion of my 3 jobs without freezing UI (or at least the animation).

I tried with runBlocking but it freezes the UI...

```
runBlocking() {
   jobA!!.join()
   jobB!!.join()
   jobC!!.join()
}
```

How can I wait for my 3 jobs without freezing UI ?

Thanks in advance,
Sorry for my english,
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to launch another coroutine using `Main` `CorotineContext` and wait for jobs there:

```
CoroutineScope(Main).launch {
    jobA!!.join()
    jobB!!.join()
    jobC!!.join()
}
```

Comment: Works fine !  Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Worked smoothly, Thanks a lot